# picking image without UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I m new in iphone.I need to know that how to get image from library without using UIImagePicker controller in iphone.

i m picking image from library through UIImagePicker and store image name in Database but i want to fetch that images back from library with name without UIImagePicker controller.

can anyone tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is uiimagePickercontroller. Or else You can save it in your database n retrieve it n display it on UIActionSheet as it will give look of imagepicker without using it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , using UIImagePicker controller is the best way to do this but imposes UI restrictions. 
You can use ALAssetsLibrary to pick up images and show it in your own UI.
Third and the most dirty technique would be to pick the image from imagepickercontroller and save it in your documentsDir to pick from there in future(I would not recommend this technique but this is a way to do it without imagepickercontroller).

Answer (score -1):

You can try NSFileManager to access files of the camera directory /User/Media/DCIM/. And then open the files and loading them into UIImageViews. Not sure on how Apple would react on this as you're accessing files outside your apps sandbox.

Comment: If you want your app to be rejected, this is a great way to do that.